# script tag freeze iphone safari

Tags: jquery, html

actually im facing a strange problem with ajax on iphone maybe someone can help or know the reason of this

here is the page i load via ajax with jquery

```html
<div class="pagesss">
 <button class="action_btn" data-get="box1"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Filter</button>
</div>
<div class="pagesss">
 <div id="filter_result">
 <?php
  $get_user = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id > 0 LIMIT 24");
  while($user = $get_user->fetch_assoc()){
   echo box($user);
  }
 ?>
 </div>
 ------------ emplacement 1 -----------
</div>
---------- emplacement 2 --------------
```

when i try to insert a script tag with some jquery at emplacement 2 it freeze my iphone all the time when the page load

if i put the script tag in emplacement 1 it do not freeze is there a reason why it do that ?

Comment: What is your jquery code?

Comment: i have try with very simple code like this <script>alert('hello');</script> and it trigger the hello but after that page freeze